# unusual behaviour in tcl variable ( thread package ) > tsv

Tags: tcl

The problem with this code is that , before the loop runs the first time the value of i is 0, inside the loop the value of i is still 0, but when i access the value of i inside of

```
set threadId [thread::create {
    set location [exec which jade]
    [exec $location --pretty --watch [tsv::get jadeJade [tsv::get jade i]]]
    thread::wait
}]
```

it increments to 1, the result am expecting is 0 since i did not incremente the value of i before creating the thread.

```
proc File {btn smallFrame scrFrame} {
    global scrList
    set allowedFiles [format "{\"%s\" {\"%s\"}}" "$btn" ".[string tolower $btn]"]
    puts $allowedFiles

    set files [tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $allowedFiles -multiple 1]
    tsv::set jade i 0
    foreach scrFiles $files {
        switch -exact -- [regsub -all  {(\.)} [file extension $scrFiles] ""] {
            jade {
                lappend scrList $scrFiles
                showScript $smallFrame $scrFrame
                tsv::set jadeJade [tsv::get jade i] $scrFiles

                set threadId [thread::create {
                     set location [exec which jade]
                    [exec $location --pretty --watch [tsv::get jadeJade [tsv::get jade i]]]
                    thread::wait
                }]
                tsv::incr jade i
             }
        }

    }

}
```

when trying to fix the bug i moved `tsv::incr jade i` before creating the thread, it worked but it broke the code

Comment: Well. simple race condition?  You have `tsv::incr` behind the `thread::create` but the thread might not start immediately, so it sees `1` because the `incr` runs first.

Comment: A line of code `[exec …]` looks _really_ suspicious. Why would you evaluate the result of an `exec`?

Comment: And probably `exec which jade` could be replaced by `auto_execok`. And you don't need threads to just run a bunch of executables in the background and get their results, but that is probably a matter of taste.